# How do I combine subnets?

Tags: subnet

I have the following subnets:

```
10.1.1.80  255.255.255.240
10.1.1.96  255.255.255.240
10.1.1.112 255.255.255.240
10.1.1.128 255.255.255.192
```

How can I combine all these subnets to form one single subnet so that the first usable address in the subnet is 10.1.1.81 and the last usable one is 10.1.1.190?

Comment: I've been trying to formulate an answer but I cant get it readable enough. But remember that netmasks are in fact binary and need to be of base 2. This means a subnet must be of size 1/2^n of the original adress space and the number if IPs in a subnet always is 2^m. You are asking for a 111 adress subnet but 111 is **not** base 2. (2^7 = 128)

Comment: This looks suspiciously like homework

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. This question comes across sounding suspiciously like a homework question, which is off topic here. If it is not school work, please [edit] your question to provide more context about why you are asking and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Hi. I am not in school. I am a Network Professional and CCNP certified. I can understand your point of view that this may seem as ridiculously simple question. However this was a need of one of my customers. Currently he has servers in 10.1.1.128 / 28 subnet and wants to enlarge the subnet by using addresses starting from 10.1.1.81. I told him this was not possible but he is totally convinced that this is possible. So I thought probably I am missing something really fundamental and so I posted this here. And if this is a "Networking" forum I don't understand why such questions are a problem !?

Comment: Additional Sidenote - The crazy customer also wants me to consult Cisco about subnetting ! Any ideas how to handle such people ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lowest ip is 10.1.1.80, and the highest is 
10.1.1.191 (from 10.1.1.128/26)

The smallest subnet (bigest mask) to cover both is **10.1.1.0/24**

When you sub-dived the subnet 10.1.1.0/24, by increasing the mask to /25 you get two subnets, not one can covers all the subnets in the question.

10.1.1.0/25 (Range 10.1.1.0-127)

10.1.1.128/25 (Range 10.1.1.128-255)

The ranges you provided is not continuous, and the answer **10.1.1.0/24** covers them all and the network in between and at the start and end of the ranges.